# How to replace one line to two lines or more on a text file using the "find and replace mode"?

Tags: windows, search, text-editors, find-and-replace

Right now I'm developing a script with vbscript and I need to find one specific line(with a lot of occurrences) on a 5k lines source code and replace it to two new code lines(1 line to 2 lines replacement).

I'm using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) but as far I could use any another editor to my development, I could someday confront with the same problem editing any kind of text file. I already tried to find a way on Notepad++, MS Word and even on Windows Notepad and didn't found any solution(all of them just replaced the search ocurrence with the first line of the replacement text).

[image]

**There is some way to replace one text line to two or more lines when find an occurrence with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> on a text editor?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on how your file's line endings are formatted (I'm going to assume Windows linebreaks since you said VB), you can switch the **Search Mode** to *Extended* and do something like this:

```
Find what: strLine
Replace with: line1\r\nline2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didn't actually works, notepad++ interpreted \n just as "\n", I mean, the replacement stayed with "line1\r\nline2" text.

Comment: Did you make sure to switch the Search Mode to Extended?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you told to switch to Extended mode, I will accept yours as the main answear because you answeared the solution first. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Its quite easy. If you look in the search mode you have an "Extended" mode. Use the special chars, like \n for newline.
[image]

Comment: Wow, this really worked.... When I read the "Extended(\n, \r, \t, \x..." option I didn't really understood what it is intended to do... Thank you very much.